# VSFTPD proper permission for root user

Tags: permissions, directory, vsftpd

I did set up VSFTPD on my server and can successfully login using a user that has root permission on the server. However, I cannot create any directories outside of the user's home directory. Any idea why that is?

I have the option

```
write_enable=YES
```

enabled.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

`chroot_local_user=YES`

> chroot_local_user If set to YES, local users will be (by default)
>   placed in a chroot() jail in their home directory after login.
>   Warning: This option has security implications, especially if the
>   users have upload permission, or shell access. Only enable if you know
>   what you are doing. Note that these security implications are not
>   vsftpd specific. They apply to all FTP daemons which offer to put
>   local users in chroot() jails.

[Source](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is not wise to do this.

That being said, i think you can just specify:

```
nopriv_user=root # or maybe toor
```

Try that?